# Distributing tickets into boxes

Tags: probability

Having trouble understanding this:

You have 7 tickets numbered 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7 and 7 boxes labeled A;B;C;D;E; F;G. You
wish to distribute the tickets among the boxes.

(a) How many ways are there to distribute the tickets?

*My Solution: 7^7

(b) How many ways are there to distribute the tickets if each box is to contain only one ticket?

*My Solution: 7! as it is an ordering question

(c) How many ways are there to distribute the tickets if box G is to be empty but each of the other
boxes is to contain at least one ticket?

*My Solution: Since 6 boxes will have at least 1, 6C1
... this is all I have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the steps that I would take:
1) There needs to be exactly one box with 2 tickets, so choose that box
2) You need to choose two of the seven tickets to go in said box
3) Now you have 5 empty boxes and 5 tickets, go crazy

Answer (score 0):

(a) and (b) are correct.

For (c), **Hint:** Exactly 1 box has 2 tickets.
Find this box, and the 2 tickets in it, and then find the tickets in the other boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Davis help:

1) 6C1
2) 7C2
3) 5!

Multiply altogether and voila